# I want To add road map in google Map

Tags: angular

In This Code I want to created the road map but The error is that I not founded the road I put the image because the image is showing what I say so the image
[In This Image I Show A triangle in this triangle I wanted to show some roads soo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WJno.png)

```
  LocationChoosen=false;
  Lat = 63.4313378;
  long =10.4015246;
  zoom=7;




  onChoseLocation(event)
  {
    LocationChoosen=true;
  }

  OnMapReady(map) 
 {
    This.map = map;
    This.initDrawingManager(map);
  }

<agm-map 

       [latitude]='Lat' 

       [longitude]='long'
       (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
       (mapClick)="onChoseLocation($event)"
       [zoom]='zoom'>
         <agm-marker 
              [latitude]="Lat" 
              [longitude]="long">    
        </agm-marker>

</agm-map>
```

Comment: It's difficult to know what you're trying to achieve. Please add more details.

Comment: @Pinaki yaa sure Store snapped polyline returned by the snap-to-road service

Comment: @Pinaki now its understanding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community  first i want to create a Enables the polyline drawing control. Click on the map to start drawing a polyline. Each click will add a new vertice. Double-click to stop drawing.

Comment: now if you are not understand what i want then goo to this link  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap#javascript-+-html

Comment: @Community open the map and draw a polyline and you see some road